# Schema.org isConsumableFor Property in JSON

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, structured-data

Trying to sort out how to use the schema.org property **isConsumableFor** with JSON. I set the main product as "**Raspberry Pi 4**" and the isConsumableFor product "**Power Supply**".

The JSON snippet is built for "**Raspberry Pi 4**":

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"Product",
    "name":"Raspberry Pi 4",
    "image":[
        "raspberry-pi-4-model-b.jpg",
        "raspberry-pi-4-model-b-2.jpg",
    ],
    "description":"Raspberry Pi 4 ...",
    "offers":{
        "@type":"AggregateOffer",
        "offerCount":1,
        "highPrice":"40.00 ",
        "lowPrice":"40.00 ",
        "priceCurrency":"EUR",
        "offers":[
            {
                "@type":"Offer",
                "priceCurrency":"EUR",
                "priceValidUntil":"2019-11-09T21:50:32+01:00",
                "url":"Raspberry-Pi-4-Model-B",
                "price":"40.00 ",
                "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/New",
                "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

On the page of Raspberry Pi 4 where do I have to kick the property "**isConsumableFor**"?
To Raspberry Pi 4 or to Power Supply?

```
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Product",
    "isConsumableFor":{ 
        "@context":"http://schema.org/",
        "@type":"Product",
        "name":"Raspberry Pi 4",
        "url":"example.com",
    },
}
```

or that way but if there are more consumable products available for Raspberry Pi 4 than it will repeat all the time the Raspberry Pi 4 where one time should be enough for all accessories:

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"Product",
    "name":"Power Supply",
    "image":[
        "psu.jpg",
        "psu-2.jpg",
    ],
    "description":"Power Supply ...",
    "offers":{
        "@type":"AggregateOffer",
        "offerCount":1,
        "highPrice":"8.00 ",
        "lowPrice":"8.00 ",
        "priceCurrency":"EUR",
        "offers":[
            {
                "@type":"Offer",
                "priceCurrency":"EUR",
                "priceValidUntil":"2019-11-09T21:50:32+01:00",
                "url":"powersupply",
                "price":"8.00 ",
                "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/New",
                "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock",
            }
        ]
    },
    "isConsumableFor":{ 
        "@context":"http://schema.org/",
        "@type":"Product",
        "name":"Raspberry Pi 4",
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying your JSON-LD to the below will make it valid as far as the [Structured Data Testing Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) is concerned, but there are a couple of caveats to this approach depending on how you generate your content.

I believe the best approach would be to take advantage of a global identifier (`id`):

**Raspberry Pi**

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"Product",
    "id":"https://example.com/raspberrypi4",
    "name":"Raspberry Pi 4",
    "price":"49"
    ...
}
```

**Power Supply**

```
{
    "@context":"http://schema.org/",
    "@type":"Product",
    "name":"Power Supply",
    "image":[
        "psu.jpg",
        "psu-2.jpg"
    ],
    "description":"Power Supply ...",
    "offers":{
        "@type":"AggregateOffer",
        "offerCount":1,
        "highPrice":"8.00 ",
        "lowPrice":"8.00 ",
        "priceCurrency":"EUR",
        "offers":[
            {
                "@type":"Offer",
                "priceCurrency":"EUR",
                "priceValidUntil":"2019-11-09T21:50:32+01:00",
                "url":"powersupply",
                "price":"8.00 ",
                "itemCondition":"http://schema.org/New",
                "availability":"http://schema.org/InStock"
            }
        ]
    },
    "isConsumableFor":{ 
        "@type":"Product",
        "name":"Raspberry Pi 4",
        "id":"https://example.com/raspberrypi4",
        "offers":[{
            "@type":"Offer",
            "price":"49"
        }]
    }
}
```

As you can see because `isConsumableFor` requires a `Product` - that `Product` will still require `offers`, `Review`, or `aggregateRating` - so you would at least need to provide one of those properties (in this example I'm using `Offer` with `price`).

Unfortunately `isConsumableFor` is not very well documented [on schema.org](https://schema.org/isConsumableFor) - and as of this this writing - this SO question is actually in the [top four Google results for the property](https://www.google.com/search?q=schema.org%20isconsumablefor&oq=schema.or).

Personally I feel requiring an `id` or `url` for a nested `Product` should appease the requirements for `Offer`/`aggregateRating`/`Review`. I chalk it up to the fact that Schema is still ever growing.

With that said, the larger question might be - What are you using this Schema for? If you're looking to use it to improve Google results - I personally believe you won't find much benefit, regardless of how you use it. If you're trying to connect your data through another system via JSON-LD, then I wouldn't take the [Structured Data Testing](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool) tool too seriously.